# Boolean Logic in Java

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I have come across a problem in Boolean logic in which you must assign Boolean values to each of the three variables, therefore making each equation unequal to each other.

The problem specifies:

```
!b && (c || !d) != !(b || !c && d)
```

I've tried solving the problem with a guess and check method, but I haven't had any luck quite yet. Is there a way to solve the problem algebraically? I'm working in Java.

Comment: Bring out the good old truth tables.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is theoretical. It would better suit http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Isn't this basically SAT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a trick question. Consider applying De Morgan's law to the expression on the left, after applying a double negation:

```
!!(!b && (c || !d))
!(b || !(c || !d))
!(b || !c && d)
```

In other words, there is no such combination because the two are logically equivalent.

Comment: I was just about to mention De Morgan's laws in a comment (+1)

Comment: This was of great help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution to this kind of problem can often be checking the formular for what seems to be the most "powerful" value. Here I'd say that is `b`.
So let's go through the examples with `b == true` and `b == false`.

First though, let's add some more parenthesis so it's clear what is what:

```
  !b && (c || !d) != !(b || !c && d)
= (!b && (c || !d)) != !(b || (!c && d))
```

If `b == true` then:

```
   (!true && (c || !d)) != !(true || (!c && d))
=> (false && (c || !d)) != !(true || (!c && d))
=> false != !true
=> false != false
=> false
```

And if `b == false` then:

```
   (!false && (c || !d)) != !(false || (!c && d))
=> (true && (c || !d)) != !(!c && d)
=> (c || !d) != (c || !d)
=> false
```

So this can never be fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some rules of boolean logic:

```
!(a || b) = !a && !b
!(a && b) = !a || !b
```

Apply them to the right hand side:

```
!(b || !c && d) = !b && !(!c && d) = !b && (c || !d)
```